# Cannot deserialize the current json array / getting data by id from rest api to winforms

Tags: c#

I have a problem deserializing while getting data from rest api by id in `datagridview`, any ideas how I could solve it?

```
HttpResponseMessage message = await clint.GetAsync("/api/Student/search?id=" + findId);
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
if ((int)message.StatusCode == 200)
{
    var s = message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var ss = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Student>(s.Result);
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(ss.id, ss.name, ss.address, ss.beginYear, ss.studyProgram);
    responsBox.Text = message.StatusCode.ToString();
}
else
{
    responsBox.Text = message.StatusCode.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show("ID:llä ei löydy oppilasta.");
}
```

Here's my student class:

```
public class Student
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string beginYear { get; set; }
    public string studyProgram { get; set; }
}
```

Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3])

Comment: What does `s.Result` contain?  What error are you getting?

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'RestClient.Student' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array

Comment: The exception you mention should be raising in line "var ss = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Student>(s.Result);"  but to understand what is happening, we need to know the content of variable "s" in the previous line.